# Multi-task learning with mutually exclusive tasks?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pytorch, multitasking

[image: Multi-task learning]

I wish to perform multi-task learning by performing segmentation and classification using shared layers as shown in the figure. However, the output 1 will be a segmentation mask that works with a different loss function like Dice loss and output 2 works with softmax activations to deliver class probabilities. Also, the data are mutually exclusive, the segmentation task comes from natural image domain, and classification from medical image domain. Is Keras or Pytorch have a defined way or examples demonstrating such multi-task learning tasks?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to alternate between the two tasks while training.
I will also assume you are going to mix the two tasks within the same batch.

You can make a custom [`Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset) that returns

```py
class MixedDataset(Dataset):
  # ...
  def __getitem__(self, index):
    # ... get data according to index
    return img, seg, seg_flag, class, class_flag
```

for medical images the `seg` is going to be a dummy mask and the `seg_flag` is going to be zero, while the `class` is going to be the target class and `class_flag` is 1.
On the other hand, for natural images `seg` is going to be the desired segmentation mask and `seg_flag` is 1, while `class` is going to be a dummy and `class_flag` is zero.

Now you can run your training code:

```py
for i, (img, seg, seg_flag, class, class_flag) in train_loader:
  opt.zero_grad()
  pred_mask, pred_class = model(img)  # predict both
  loss_seg = seg_flag * dice_loss_fuction(pred_mask, seg)
  loss_class = class_flag * cross_entropy_loss_function(pred_class, class)
  (loss_seg + loss_class).backward()
  opt.step()
```